# How reconcile disconnected data (inserts/updates/deletes)?

Tags: dataset, data-synchronization

We don’t have wi-fi in every area of our outdoor facilities. So, we have the need for users to work with data sets disconnected and then sync back up.  Our thought is to have the user’s PC poll for wi-fi every 60 seconds.  If it sees it, it connects and uploads/downloads data.

So let’s say a user’s PC grabs a data set and goes off and works locally with it (inserts/updates/deletes).  Meanwhile, someone else is inserting/updating/deleting the same data set directly in the database (someone back in the office).  How then, can we rectify everything?

E.g. if record “1” has a value of “blue” and the user downloads it locally.  It then changes “blue” to “red” while offline.  Once wi-fi is found, it could just update, but if an office user had changed “blue” to “green” it might be a bad thing.  “Last one wins” I suppose could get us in trouble.. especially if the offline user inserts a record not realizing that the office user has as well.

This question really isn't how to do something technically.  I suppose it's more about looking for a best practice.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to reinvent the wheel, there is already a tools to synchronize database e.g [symmetricds](http://www.symmetricds.org/) to facilitate data synchronize for inserts/updates/deletes operations.